# communicate between Arduino and PC from Usb Serialport ports(C++ console Application)

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, serial-port, arduino

for my small project i was trying to send small messages to the Arduino and based on the message it well turn off and on it's output port.
i have tried it in c# it's worked properly, but i want to do it in c++ console application..
my c++ knowledge is not good, and i searched it but i didn't found and understandable solutions for it.

i just need to send and retrieve messages from my Arduino via serial Port in c++ console application.

this is my working C# code.

```
    using System.IO.Ports;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM8", 9600);
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                port.Open();
                port.Write("1");
                port.Close();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                port.Open();
                String s = port.ReadLine();
                port.Close();
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: You are not using SerialPort correctly.  Closing the port immediately after Write() will prevent whatever you write from being written.  That takes time, serial ports are slow.  You are jerking the floor mat too early.  The only sensible use is to open the port when you start your program and not close it until you terminate it.  Maybe it works by accident in your C# app, odds that you can reproduce it in C++ are *not* good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Arduino website had an great [example](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows) how to interface Arduino and C++ in Windows.
I think if you include the described SerialClass.h (header), Serial.cpp (source code file) in your project and adapt the example main.cpp file this could be a solution for you.